What to write as a "current institution" in a postdoc grant form, right after PhD?
When submitting a postdoc grant application, what should an applicant write in the current institution section if they just recently received their PhD and aren't employed yet? It is the grant type that supports specifically recent and soon to be PhD holders on their further path rather than mobility or staff exchange (experienced researchers). Thank you.

Is it required that an institution sponsor you?  For a GRFP (graduate student), it doesn't go through an institution at time of proposal.  Many postdoc applications do require the name of the institution that will receive the money though.  If you can provide the sponsor name, that would help.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin Thank you for replying. Yes, I have the host institution where I'll move to work if I get the grant (in Europe). There is a separate field for a host, though, which is why I am confused.

If there's time before the deadline, you could contact the funding organization and ask for clarification.  I don't think you'll annoy anyone by doing so.
If not, then I would assume you would list the university where you received your PhD.  My guess is that the form creators were thinking of the situation of a "soon to be PhD holder", in which case their "current institution" would be the one where they expect to receive their PhD.  The only difference in your case is the timing, such that you've actually completed and received your degree (congratulations!) before filling out the application, but they are probably expecting this field to tell them the applicant's PhD institution.  Especially since, as you say, there is a separate field for the prospective postdoc institution.

I agree with the idea of asking the sponsor.  In the US, when you are between institutions, they usually want the institution that will receive the funding.  I am not able to comment on European sponsors though, if the host is already listed, you may be correct.  Asking the sponsor is the right choice here.

That's good advice. Thank you very much!
